# Temporaries lifetime in N3290 C++ draft

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, temporary-objects, dangling-pointer

A point from N3290 C++ draft, § 12.2, 5th point, line 10.

> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The
>   temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the
>   complete object of a  subobject to which the reference is bound
>   persists for the lifetime of the  reference except:
>
> A temporary bound to a reference in a new-initializer (5.3.4)
>   persists until   the completion of the full-expression containing the
>   new-initializer.     [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct S { int mi; const std::pair<int,int>& mp; };
> S a { 1, {2,3} };
> S* p = new S{ 1, {2,3} };// Creates dangling reference
> ```
>
> — end example ]   [ Note: This may introduce a dangling reference,
>   and implementations are    encouraged  to issue a warning in such a
>   case. — end note ]

This is the added point when compared to C++03. But the example is not understandable for me. Can you please explain this point with any other example?

I know what dangling references and temporary objects are and that `std::pair` holds two values of possibly different data types.

Comment: Note that RValue-refs (which is what this looks like you're talking about) changed significantly several times as the standard was modified. If you're not using the FDIS (or better yet, the actual standard), you might not be seeing the correct explanation anyway.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: That text remains as shown in the FDIS, and while I don't have access to the finalized standard, there should be no change from the FDIS.

Comment: @David: If it matches FDIS then it should be correct, yes. (I have access to neither the FDIS nor the final standard at the moment)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Temporaies in general last only to the end of the expression that they were created in:

```
#include <complex>


void func()
{
    std::complex<int>   a; // Real variable last until the end of scope.

    a = std::complex<int>(1,2) + std::complex<int>(3,4);
     // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  Creates a temporary object
     //                         This is destroyed at the end of the expression.
     // Also note the result of the addition creates a new temporary object
     // Then uses the assignment operator to change the variable 'a'
     // Both the above temporaries and the temporary returned by '+'
     // are destroyed at ';'
```

If you create a temporary object and bind it to a reference. You extend its lifespan to the same lifespan of the reference it is bound too.

```
    std::complex<int> const& b  = std::complex<int>(5,6);
                      //           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Temporary object
                      // ^^^^                       Bound to a reference.
                      //                            Will live as long as b lives 
                      //                            (until end of scope)
```

The exception to this rule is when the temporary is bound to a reference in a new initializer.

```
    S* p1 = new S{ 1, {2,3} };
    // This is the new C++11 syntax that does the `equivalent off`:

    S* p2 = new S {1, std::pair<int,int>(2,3) };
                 //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    Temporary object.
                 //                              This lives until the end of the 
                 //                              expression that belongs to the new.
                 //                              ie the temporary will be destroyed
                 //                              when we get to the ';'
```

But here we are binding the new temporary object to the member

`const std::pair<int,int>& mp;`

This is a const reference. But the temporary object it is bound to will be destroyed at the ';' in the above expression so mp will be a reference to an object that no longer exists when you try and use it in subsequent expressions.

```
}
```

Comment: So, colloquially you could say that "class member references cannot extend the lifetime of temporaries passed through the constructor". That's a good point to take home. Nice answer, by the way!

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Interestingly the quote seems to indicate the opposite, well not quite, but kind of. The fact that it only mentions *new-initializer* (and *constructor argument* in a previous line that has been cut out of the question), together with the lack of comment in the second line of the code example seems to indicate that the intent is allowing that second line not to create a dangling reference. I.e. nothing in the standard says that during aggregate initialization the lifetime is not extended. On the other hand, both g++4.5 and clang++2.8 create a dangling reference for that second line

Comment: @David: Ah, yes. So it should be "dynamically allocated objects cannot extend the lifetime of temporaries", is that it? That actually makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: :) Still a little more complext than that, non-aggregates require the use of a constructor, and that is covered in the point I noted above, and I am not even sure about the intention of that particular change, but the best I can come up with would be: *only aggregates with no dynamic storage **might** be able to extend the lifetime of a temporary by binding a constant reference* The *might* indicating that I have not seen anywhere in the standard where that is disallowed, even if the compilers I have access to don't.

Comment: David: Hmmm. If only `new` expressions are excluded, then any other expression, including constructor calls for automatic allocation, should be *included* in the situations which extend the temporary's lifetime. Does the standard just not address this at all? I'll run some tests with GCC, just out of curiosity.

Comment: Actually, it might be that constructor calls in direct initialization don't constitute "binding a temporary to a const-reference", and rather, the temporary only lives for the duration of the constructor call. That is, the fact that the function call itself binds its argument to another const reference isn't relevant to the original temporary.

Comment: @Kerrek: I think in this situation we are binding the temporary to the parameter used in the constructor (the compiler generated one). So the lifetime is extended to the lifetime of the parameter (unfortunately this is not any longer than temporary so it is still destroyed at the end of scope). It is this hidden binding that the comment in the standard is trying to elucidate on so that people don't think it is bound directly to the member and thus extended to the lifetime of the object.